# Get & set drop down value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If user select an option from dropdown it will shown it a textbox but if he select option having value "Other" then a row will appear to type value for other.

my code works fine except when option value is not equal to "Other"

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function setAndReset(box) {
if(box.value == 'Other'){
    $("#ShowHide").hide();
}
document.FormName.hiddenInput.value = box.value;

}
//-->
</script>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<form id="FormName" action="" method="get" name="FormName">
    <select name="choice1" size="1" onchange="setAndReset(this);">
    <option value="one">first</option>
    <option value="two">second</option>
    <option value="three">third</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="hiddenInput" value="">
    <tablt><tr id="ShowHide"><td>
        <input type="text" name="otherInput">
    </td></tr></table>
    <input type="submit" name="submitButtonName">
</form>
</body>
```

but it does not show/hide  & does not set value in textbox.

If it's solve using jquery then i will be thankful to you for you code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name=choice1]").change(function() {
       $(this).val() == 'other' ? $("#ShowHide").show() : $("#ShowHide").hide();
    });
});
```

and lose the inline onchange function call. [Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/VyCH6/).

Comment: you want $(this).val() == "other" not "Other"

Comment: @brad - yep, ran into that while I was doing up a little demo.

Answer (score 1):

I like karim79's answer, but prefer it a bit more compact:

```
$(function() {
    $("select[name=choice1]").change(function() {
       $("#ShowHide").toggle($(this).val() === "other");
    });
});
```

- Instead of `$(document).ready(f)`, do `$(f)`, it's exactly the same
- Instead of a loose `==`, use `===` for a exact comparison (in this case it doesn't matter, but `==` can behave strangely so you should avoid it everywhere)
- Use `toggle(b)` instead of `show()`/`hide()`

Comment: i didn't realize toggle took a boolean!  nice and succinct